# CSS Hexagon Border does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, border

I need just a hexagon shaped border. I found a generator website [CSS Hexagon](http://csshexagon.com/) and copied exactly the code given. But I get a completely different result in the same browser with the same doctype.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style  type="text/css">
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 190px; 
  height: 109.70px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 54.85px 0;
  border-left: solid 10px #ff2828;
  border-right: solid 10px #ff2828;
}
.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 134.35px;
  height: 134.35px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 17.8249px;
}
.hexagon:before {
  top: -67.1751px;
  border-top: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
  border-right: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
}
.hexagon:after {
  bottom: -67.1751px;
  border-bottom: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
  border-left: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="hexagon">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see, the border isn't the way it should be.

[image: Picture of the Result]

So what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for every help!

Comment: Try normalising first like they do in http://csshexagon.com/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they left out that you also need this rule:

```
*,*:before,*:after {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style  type="text/css">
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 190px; 
  height: 109.70px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 54.85px 0;
  border-left: solid 10px #ff2828;
  border-right: solid 10px #ff2828;
}
.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 134.35px;
  height: 134.35px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 17.8249px;
}
.hexagon:before {
  top: -67.1751px;
  border-top: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
  border-right: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
}
.hexagon:after {
  bottom: -67.1751px;
  border-bottom: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
  border-left: solid 14.1421px #ff2828;
}
*,*:before,*:after {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="hexagon">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```